# Suppress the default input of a key in Android

Tags: java, android, keyevent, suppress, t9

I have an `edittext` where I'm trying to over ride the default input of physical keys to replace with custom input for each key. My code works fine to add the input that I want, but I cannot seem to suppress the default input, which shows up alongside my input. At the present, I am scanning the text, removing the unwanted input, replacing the text, and repositioning the caret - but this solution is highly impractical.

Just for context -  I'm targeting a device that has a traditional number keypad, and does not have support for standard android input procedures. The device comes preinstalled with Latin and Korean input, and I am trying to create a T9 solution for other languages, not preinstalled. This method seems to be the only way to do it on this device.

How can I suppress the default input?

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4730208/6207504) question, but for Android.

Skipping over my temporary solution, here is the code that intercepts the key events. I need to suppress the default input at the indicated position in the code:

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event){
    super.onKeyUp(KeyCode, event);
    if (KeyCode>6 && KeyCode<19){
    //todo: suppress default input here!
        switch (KeyCode){
            case 7:  buttonHandler(R.id.Button0); break;
            case 8:  buttonHandler(R.id.Button1); break;
            case 9:  buttonHandler(R.id.Button2); break;
            case 10: buttonHandler(R.id.Button3); break;
            case 11: buttonHandler(R.id.Button4); break;
            case 12: buttonHandler(R.id.Button5); break;
            case 13: buttonHandler(R.id.Button6); break;
            case 14: buttonHandler(R.id.Button7); break;
            case 15: buttonHandler(R.id.Button8); break;
            case 16: buttonHandler(R.id.Button9); break;
            case 17: buttonHandler(R.id.ButtonStar); break;
            case 18: buttonHandler(R.id.ButtonHash); break;
        }
    }
}
```